# Display woocommerce product variation images on custom place in template

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product-variations

What I want to do is, to display an additional product variation image, based on the variation selection, at a custom place in product page.

I was successful to use the hook `woocommerce_show_product_images` and add the product image with all the variation images this way. This works as the variation image switches upon selection. But this way I get all the thumbnails, sliding functions and magnifier stuff too.

Then I tried to get the variation images on other ways. First I used this code.

I placed it in `content-single-product.php` in child theme:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>

<img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```

This gives me the main product image in the position I want. But it can not switch upon the variation selection.

After that I found another resource with this lines of code:

In `content-single-product.php`

```
<?php
    // get the product variations
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    if ( !empty( $product_variations ) ) {
        ?>
    <div class="product-variation-images">
    <?php
    foreach($product_variations as $product_variation) {
        // get the slug of the variation
        $product_attribute_name = $product_variation['attributes'];
        ?>
        <div class="product-variation-image product-variation-<?php echo $product_attribute_name ?>" id="product-variation-<?php echo $product_variation['variation_id']; ?>" data-attribute="<?php echo $product_attribute_name ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $product_variation['image_src']; ?>" alt="">
        </div><!-- #product-variation-image -->
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This results in a blank page after the header is displayed.

Then I tried to use a for loop, again in `content-single-product.php`

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";
}
```

Which does nothing, no error no image.

> Update

Now I've figured it out and got the function to execute correctly.
There was missing a 
`global $product;` at the beginning.

But these both functions are displaying all the variation images available as a list **instead** of switching the images upon the variation selected.

Here is the working function in `functions.php`

```
add_action ('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'test_code', 5 
);
function test_code () {
global $product; 

    if ( $product->has_child() ) {

$variations = $product->get_children();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $variation ) ) {

            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $variation );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is several way to get the variation thumbnail, and in your second try you was almost there but there is some tiny mistake in your code.

in your second try :

**instead of :**

```
<img src="<?php echo $product_variation['image_src']; ?>" alt="">
```

**you can use :**

```
<img src="<?php echo $product_variation['image']['src']; ?>" alt="">
```

or in my opinion better way you can do like following but of course it's totally up to you:

```
if ( $product->has_child() ) {

    $variations = $product->get_children();

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $variation ) ) {

                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $variation );
        }
    }
}
```